# Display a landscape ad through IronSource in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads, ironsource

So, I'm creating an app that is locked to landscape view. I'm looking to have ads play at specific times, such as after completing a few levels or the player dies too many times.

These ads should be displayed in landscape view, which I'm struggling to figure out how to do.

NOTE : I'm displaying ads through IronSource and the code below displays the ads in portrait mode.

Current code :

```
public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        if (IronSource.Agent.isInterstitialReady())
        {
            IronSource.Agent.showInterstitial();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.